# C# FileSystemWatcher not firing off events - why not?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

here is my code... no FileSystemWatcher events are ever hit wen creating a new file into the Foo directory. What is wrong with my code?

I am testing this from an NUnit test by calling fileMonitorService.StartMonitoringForNewFiles(new RobotParameters()).

```
// attribute for autofac IoC
    [AutoRegister]
    public class FileMonitorService
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher _fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        public void StartMonitoringForNewFiles(RobotParameters parameters)
        {

        _fileWatcher.Path = @"c:\testfiles\foo";
            _fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                NotifyFilters.FileName |
                NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                NotifyFilters.Size |
                NotifyFilters.Security;

            _fileWatcher.Filter = "*.xlsx";
            _fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((sender, e)  => OnFileCreated(sender, e, parameters));
            _fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler((sender, e) => OnFileRenamed(sender, e, parameters));
            _fileWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
            _fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }

        public void StopMonitoringForFiles()
        {
_fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }

        private void OnFileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e, RobotParameters parameters)
        {
            parameters.FileToProcess = e.FullPath;
            parameters.FileCreated = true;
        }

        private void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e, RobotParameters parameters)
        {
            parameters.FileToProcess = e.FullPath;
            parameters.FileCreated = true;
        }

        private void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            var foo = e.GetException();
        }


    }
```

Comment: FSW does not have a bug, consider focusing on the testing code.  That it can't see OnError is not pretty btw.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but you have the filter set to .xlsx files.  Are the test files you create using that extension?

Comment: Andy yeah it is a .xlsx file... I copy it into the Foo directory and none of the events are raised. The breakpoints in each event are never hit for some reason.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. The events are rised as expected. Implemented as posted here. The error is somewhere else (the class is not instantiated correctly?).

Comment: You realize that should the events get raised, you are just going to continually overwrite the properties of `parameters` since a single shared instance gets passed into every event. If the event fires twice in quick succession for two different files before you process it (with I assume some other code not shown here) what do you plan on doing?

Comment: Jimi thanks for testing will keep trying on my end. pinkfloydx33 good observation but yeah, I am aware of this - it will only ever be one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get this to work and based on my google research, many others have had the same problem. I also tried using System.Timers.Timer and it's Elapsed event would not raise  either. Google research showed lots of others having this problem too. All my code was in a try/catch and no errors were ever raised by either. I unfortunately had to write my own file monitor code and while it is not pretty, it works. I'm posting it for any others who may have this problem and who may be looking for a custom solution.

```
public  class FileMonitorService
    {
        private bool stopProcessing = false;

        public  void StartMonitoringForNewFiles(RobotParameters parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                while (stopProcessing == false)
                {

                        stopProcessing = IsFileReady(parameters);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);      // sleeps for 5 seconds 

                    if (stopProcessing == true)
                    {
                        break;      // get out of loop since file is ready
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private bool IsFileReady(RobotParameters parameters)
        {
                try
                {
// code to try opening a file goes here
// or code to see if files exist goes here

// assuming file was opened with no errors and is ready for processing

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

// file is not ready for processing
// and could not be opened
                    return false;

                }
            }


            return false;

            }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Never too late to get the answer. You only needed to make a small adjustment:

```
_fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((sender, e) => OnFileCreated(sender, e, parameters));
_fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler((sender, e) => OnFileRenamed(sender, e, parameters));
```

Just remove the new FileSystemEventHandler:

```
_fileWatcher.Created += (sender, e) => OnFileCreated(sender, e, parameters);
_fileWatcher.Renamed += (sender, e) => OnFileRenamed(sender, e, parameters);
```

This is what worked for me.